# over/during - interchangeability and difference

Tags: prepositions

I'm considering going to France **over** the christmas holidays.

I'm considering going to France **during** the christmas holidays.

Or

I went to my friend's place **over** the weekend.

I went to my friend's place **during** the weekend.

What's the difference between the first two and the second two sentences? 
Are **over** and **during** interchangeable in some scenarios?

Comment: They are fairly similar. Possibly "over" will carry the sense of "for the whole holiday", while "during" might cover just a part of it, but it's something you'd have to clarify.

Comment: A look at ngrams suggests 'during' has always been much more common in both British and English. 'Over' has always been more common in American than British, but in recent decades, its use has begun rising in both.

Comment: @ralph.m 
So you'd derive the pretty much same meaning from either sentence?

Comment: over and during do not mean the same thing. For pete's sake.

Answer (score -1):

during the weekend or holiday, means at some point during those times.

I went to France during the week for two days, not over the weekend.

**It does not necessarily mean the whole time (weekend or holidays).**

That's why we would say:

- I went to France for the weekend. or over
- I went to France for the holidays. or over

to mean the entire weekend or the entire holidays.

**for** and **over** would have the same meaning in those two cases. Not during.

Comment: Please disregad the downvote.